# DllImport LoadLibrary and LoadLibraryEx from kernel32 works on .NET Framework 4.0 but not on 4.5+

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, native, dllimport

I have a piece of code that loads a native dll, it loads the dll using LoadLibrary from kernel32 using DllImport

```
    public static IntPtr Load(string fileName)
    {
        IntPtr num = LoadLibrary(fileName);
        if (num == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
        return num;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllFilePath);
```

This piece of code works on .NET framework 4.0 but on 4.5+ it throws most of the times `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: '%1 is not a valid Win32 application'`, it is not consistent sometimes it say the operation was successful in the error message.

this code doesn't fail on .NET framework 4.0 and return the pointer.

At first I thought it is an environment issue but tested on different ones same issue. Not experienced with PInvoke and couldn't find this asked on stack overflow. Can someone lead me to some pointers.

Doesn't matter on Run configurations, tried x86 and x64 same issue

Same thing happens with LoadLibraryEx.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 4.5 did introduce a change regarding "AnyCPU" (see [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-45-and-visual-studio-11/)), but you say you've also explicitly tried x86 and x64. What is the architecture of the library you're trying to load? Can you perhaps try again setting an explicit architecture?

Comment: Classic symptoms of 32/64 bit mismatch